# d3 collapse tree - update node visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree, refresh, tree-nodes

Hey im working with that [example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html) . Watch below for my modified Sourcecode.

Depending on the propertie "enabled" of a node it is coloured green or red.

```
                nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 10)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return d.enabled ? "green" : "red";
                    });
```

I have another .js-file for modifying the nodes enabled property. After changing the property i want to refresh the visualization of the tree. The click event is working.
But i have no idea how to refresh the tree in my source code below.

So here is the source code for my tree widget:

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dojo/_base/array",
"dojo/on",
"ct/_Connect",
"ct/_lang"

],
function (declare, WidgetBase, d_array, on, Connect, ct_lang) {
    return declare([WidgetBase], {
        resize: function (dim) {
            this._tree.size([dim.h, dim.w]);
        },

        postCreate: function () {
            this.inherited(arguments);
            var that = this;

            var d3 = this.d3;
            var mapModel = this.mapModel;
            var div = this.domNode;

            var m = [20, 120, 20, 120],
                w = 900 - m[1] - m[3],
                h = 900 - m[0] - m[2],
                i = 0,
                root;

            var tree = this._tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .size([h, w]);

            var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                .projection(function (d) {
                    return [d.y, d.x];
                });

            var vis = d3.select(div).append("svg:svg")

                .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
                .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
                .append("svg:g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");


            // var myjson for treedata


            var myjson = traverseTree(mapModel.getRoot(), {});


            function traverseTree(node) {
                var resultChildren = [];     
                var resultEnabled = node.get("enabled");


                var children = node.get("children");  
                if (children && children.length) {
                    d_array.forEach(
                        children,          // 1.Parameter
                        function (child) {      // 2. Parameter von forEach Funktion
                             resultChildren.push(traverseTree(child));   
                        }
                    );
                }

                return {
                    name: node.id,  // gebe "name : node.id" zurrück
                    children: resultChildren, 
                    enabled: resultEnabled
                };


            }


            root = myjson;
            root.x0 = h / 2;
            root.y0 = 0;


            function toggleAll(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d.children.forEach(toggleAll);
                    toggle(d);
                }
            }

            // Initialize the display to show a few nodes.
            root.children.forEach(toggleAll);
            toggle(root);


            update(root);


            function update(source) {
                var duration = d3.event && d3.event.altKey ? 5000 : 500;

                // Compute the new tree layout.
                var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

                // Normalize for fixed-depth.
                nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                    d.y = d.depth * 180;
                });

                // Update the nodes…
                var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function (d) {
                        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                    });

                // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
                var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                    })

                    //click once
                    .on("click", function (d) {
                        toggle(d);
                        update(d);

                        that.onNodeClick(d);


                    })

                    //connect p


                    //click twice
                    .on("dblclick", function (d) {
                        console.log("TEST FOR DOUBLECLICK");
                    });


                nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")

                    .attr("r", 1e-6)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    });


                nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
                    .attr("x", function (d) {
                        return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                    })
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
                        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                    })
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.name;
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);


                // Transition nodes to their new position.
                var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                    });

                nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 10)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return d.enabled ? "green" : "red";
                    });

                nodeUpdate.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1)


                // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                    })
                    .remove();

                nodeExit.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-6);


                nodeExit.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

                // Update the links…
                var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(tree.links(nodes), function (d) {
                        return d.target.id;
                    });

                // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
                link.enter().insert("svg:path", "g")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                    })
                    .transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", diagonal);

                // Transition links to their new position.
                link.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", diagonal);

                // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
                link.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                    })
                    .remove();

                // Stash the old positions for transition.
                nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                    d.x0 = d.x;
                    d.y0 = d.y;
                });
            }

            // Toggle children.
            function toggle(d) {
                if (d.children) {
                    d._children = d.children;
                    d.children = null;
                } else {
                    d.children = d._children;
                    d._children = null;
                }
            }

        },
        onNodeClick: function (e) {
        }

    });
});
```

So my question is: How do i modify my tree (update/refresh/whatever) after changing nodes properties?

In other words: I want to do [this](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/02/update-d3js-data-dynamically-button.html) on my code example.

Comment: You need to redraw the tree.

Comment: Yeah i noticed myself that the function "traverseTree" needs to run again. So the whole postCreate method needs to run again. Tried it like that: _setStatusChangeAttr: function (e) {
                        this.postCreate();

            }                                                                                 Doesnt work

Comment: In that function, you're appending a new SVG regardless of whether one is there or not. When you update, you need to select the existing elements and update their attributes, styles etc.

Comment: It would help if you could provide a complete working example.

Comment: i can do that at the weekend. if is just need to redraw my tree this is the only essentiel code for my problem. The treenodes depend on a layerstatus in a webapp. Another question. Is it possible to reload the widget where my tree is in or the whiole Border Container?

Comment: The point of having a complete example would be to be able to actually try things out. You've been saying that my suggestion doesn't work for you, but without seeing what you're actually doing it's hard to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Hey thank you lars. i jsut did it after some sleep :)

Comment: Would you mind to share with us because I need to do the same thing too :)

Comment: just try to get the update function standing alone. You can trigger it than (for example with dojo/connect)